# JBoss: how to fix IncompatibleClassChangeError; Failed to link org/apache/cxf/ws/policy/AssertionBuilderRegistry on jboss 7?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, cxf, jboss7.x

I'm working on an old legacy java webapp and am having to upgrade cxf artifacts/dependencies due to security violations of older jars. I've had to update several versions in the pom.xml and do some juggling of dependency exclusions. Further complicating this is our local dev set up was Tomcat 7, but we deploy to Jboss. The app runs fine with all these updated jars in Tomcat, but when I tried to deploy it to JBoss, I got this IncompatibleClassChangeError in the title.

Since originally writing this, I've gotten JBoss 7.1.6 up and running locally and been able to reproduce this. It still runs fine in Tomcat.

Also if anyone could speculate why this is happening on jboss and not tomcat, I'd be grateful. We just have a .war that we're deploying. I assume it has something to do with all the libraries that JBoss provides. I've tried excluding the org.apache.cxf and webservices modules in jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but nothing has worked. This was my latest jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
     <exclusions>
       <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
     </exclusions>
     <exclude-subsystems>  
         <subsystem name="webservices" />  
     </exclude-subsystems> 
     <dependencies>
         <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Here's the relevant apache cxf dependencies from the pom.xml (simplified from original post):

```
    <properties>
        <cxf.version>3.3.6</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Stack trace:

> Failed to define class
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry in Module
>   "deployment.CALMPreInt2.war" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Failed to link
>   org/apache/cxf/ws/policy/AssertionBuilderRegistry (Module
>   "deployment.CALMPreInt2.war" from Service Module Loader): Implementing
>   class     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:416)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:495)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:710)    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:416)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:495)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:710)    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadClassInfoSet(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:259)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:169)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I'm probably missing other relevant bits, please let me know and I'll do my best to add them.

Comment: Full stack trace please.

Comment: I've added the stack trace